# [NextAuth]: How to programmatically login user on the back-end?

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth

I use several providers, including credentials provider (email & password)
At some point, in the app, user can ask for 'restore password' email where he should get one-time link.
After he visits the link (/api/users/quick_link?token=XXX&email) I check if the token is valid and after that my goal is to login user and to redirect him to his profile page.

What have I tried:

1. Using 'nextauth/client' signIn function, which obviously does not work on back-end
2. Checking how they do ['email' provider](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/ae26df091d6a1f4420f872051a741e036c854bcc/src/server/routes/callback.js) - the starting part is more or less the same, but it quickly start using internal functions, which I do not plan (at least now) to touch.

What I have not tried:
Using REST API.

Because I am not sure how to use it from another api. Just await fetch?

**Recap**

Short version: after visiting /api/users/login_me_asap?myemail=xxx I want to login user and redirect him.